# An ObservableCollection of a DependencyProperty is returning null

Tags: c#, wpf, datagrid, custom-controls

I am in a saga for creating a custom control with a datagrid and two buttons, one for add and another for remove elements from the datagrid. Some thing like the picture below.

[image]
.

Right now my I can add elements and bind the ItemsSorce of the datagrid directly with the Collection of my ViewModel by exposing a DependecyProperty. [Here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30899813/datagrid-inside-a-custom-control-is-not-updating) is the code in another Question I have made here. Please consider the @Sandesh corrections.

Now I want to implement the remove button by adding a behaviour that should be the same for every usage: It will remove the selected row of the datagrid. For this I add the above code to the code behind of the CustomDatagrid.xaml:

```
private void RemoveButtonClick(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
        {
            var selectedItem = CustomDataGrid.SelectedValue;

            if (selectedItem != null && Colection != null)
            {
                Colection.Remove(selectedItem);
            }
        }
```

But when I press the remove button 
the Colection return null and nothing happens.

Thanks for any help.

Comment: That `DependecyProperty` is *not* declared in any view model... it's declared in the code behind of a `UserControl`.

Comment: Hellow @Sheridan, I am not declaring the Dependecy Properties on View Model. I declare it on my View (Code Behind) of my custom control.

Answer (score 1):

You are mixing up your code collections. You take the selected item from `CustomDataGrid.SelectedValue`, but then try to remove that from your `Collection` collection. Try to remove it by data binding another property to the `CustomDataGrid.SelectedItem` property and removing that instead:

```
<DataGrid Name="CustomDataGrid" ItemsSource="{Binding Collection}" 
    SelectedItem="{Binding YourNewSelectedItemProperty}" ... />
```

...

```
Colection.Remove(YourNewSelectedItemProperty);
```

---

UPDATE >>>

To clarify further:

You can only remove an item from a collection *if that exact item actually exists in the collection*. In your case, you are using the [`SelectedValue`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.controls.primitives.selector.selectedvalue(v=vs.110).aspx) property which returns (from the linked page):

> the value of the SelectedItem, **obtained by using `SelectedValuePath`**.

Note that part that I highlighted. This does not necessarily return the actual selected item. In fact, depending on the value of the `SelectedValuePath` property, it could just return a property of the selected item. Therefore, you should use the `SelectedItem` property, or an object that is data bound to that property instead.

Comment: Hi @Sheridan, thanks for your reply. I did what you said but the problem is not in the selected item but in the `Collection` itself, because It returns null.